# How i can filter all the shopkeeper open?

Tags: postgresql

There is my table. I want to get if shopkeeper is open or close based in the last register of field 'date_register'. For example the shopkeeper = 79 the last state is Close then  it will not be returned in the query.

[image]

Comment: "I want to get" -> then do it! Start here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with

```
SELECT *, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY shopkeeper_id ORDER BY date_register DESC)
FROM shopkeepers_state
```

this gives you a table with a rank count so that for each shopkeeper_id rank 1 points to the most recent entry.
Use this as a base and apply filters:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY shopkeeper_id ORDER BY date_register DESC)
    FROM shopkeepers_state) AS ps
WHERE ps.rank = 1
AND ps.state = 'Open'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT 
    distinct on(shopkeeper_id) shopkeeper_id, state, date_register
FROM  
   shopkeepers_state
WHERE 
    state = 'Open'
ORDER BY 
    shopkeeper_id, date_register DESC;
```